# Initialize Firebase Admin SDK with only environment variables in Golang

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-admin

I'm trying to [initialize the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/), in go, using only environment variables (no access to a filesystem).

I have the `service-account-file.json` file, and can get it working locally via:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/service-account-file.json"

...

myfile.go:
app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil)
```

However, I'd like to put the contents of `service-account-file.json` into an env var, and init the firebase Admin SDK with its value.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/185) that claims you can do it via [CredentialsFromJSON](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#CredentialsFromJSON), however I can't quite figure it out.

Does anyone have this working? If so can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

```
export JSON_CREDS="{\"type\":\"service_account\",\"project_id\":\"project-id\",\"private_key_id\":\"some_number\",\"private_key\":\"\",\"client_email\":\"<api-name>api@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com\",\"client_id\":\"...\",\"auth_uri\":\"https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/o\/oauth2\/auth\",\"token_uri\":\"https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/o\/oauth2\/token\",\"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\":\"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/oauth2\/v1\/certs\",\"client_x509_cert_url\":\"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/...<api-name>api%40project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com\"}"

...

import "google.golang.org/api/option"

...

app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, option.WithCredentialsJSON([]byte(os.Getenv("JSON_CREDS"))))
```

Comment: I run into an error with this approach:
```private key should be a PEM or plain PKCS1 or PKCS8; parse error: asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:0 tag:13 length:45 isCompound:true})```
The JSON is stored as a string in the environment variable and is a valid JSON when coverted to `[]byte` (checked with `json.Valid`). Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue only using the file content escaping special characters. For me solved get the entire payload and encode to base64, then I set to an env var and use in the client startup.

```
sdk, _ := b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(os.Getenv("FIREBASE_SDK"))
opt := option.WithCredentialsJSON(sdk)
app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, opt)
```

this way worked for me